# Building tabBox with dynamically generated tabPanels but with custom UI args

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I need some help resolving this particular problem I'm trying to solve. Here's what I expect the feature to do:

1. The user will select something from a dropdown (selectInput).
2. The server will pull metrics based on the selection. Let's call it **gameMetrics**.
3. The server will build tabPanels from **gameMetrics** and render them in a tabBox with *width = NULL*.

Here is what I attempted:

## Attempt 1

**server.R**

```
output$gameMetricsPanels <- renderUI({
    # gameMetrics is a data frame of games and metrics being measured
    # input$gameSelected is the value that is selected by the user from the dropdown

    currentGame <- get_game_code(gameMetrics, input$gameSelected)

    # get_metric_groups will return a list of metrics for the selected game
    gameMetricGroups <- get_metric_groups(gameMetrics, currentGame)

    tabs <- lapply(tools::toTitleCase(gameMetricGroups), tabPanel)

    do.call(tabBox, tabs)
```

**ui.R**

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    shinyHeader, # stuff I have for header
    shinySidebar, # stuff I have for sidebar
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "dashboard",
                    fluidRow(
                        column(
                            12,
                            uiOutput("gameMetricsPanels")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Why this approach wasn't working as intended:

Because tabBox has a default *width = 6*, and I can't control that with **do.call**. I'm not an R expert and googling didn't really help.

### Attempt 2

**server.R**

```
output$gameMetricsPanels <- renderUI({
    # gameMetrics is a data frame of games and metrics being measured
    # input$gameSelected is the value that is selected by the user from the dropdown

    currentGame <- get_game_code(gameMetrics, input$gameSelected)

    # get_metric_groups will return a list of metrics for the selected game
    gameMetricGroups <- get_metric_groups(gameMetrics, currentGame)

    tabs <- list(NULL)

    for (gameMetricGroup in gameMetricGroups) {
        tab <- tabPanel(toosl::toTitleCase(gameMetricGroup), value = gameMetricGroup)
        tabs <<- c(tabs, tab)
    }

    return(tabs)
```

**ui.R**

```
# stuff similar to above attempt but without the crazy nesting for readability
fluidRow(
    column(
        12,
        tabBox(  # Here, the main difference is that I'm wrapping the uiOutput in tabBox but I don't know if that's allowed
            id = "tabMetrics",
            width = NULL,  # enforce width to match parent container
            uiOutput("gameMetricsPanels")
        )
    )
)
```

Why this approach didn't work:

Nothing shows up as tabs...

Comment: Can you amend Attempt 1 to have your own tabBox function that just creates a tabBox with the width of whatever you want?

Comment: So I did try `do.call(tabBox(width = NULL), tabs)`, but Shiny didn't like that and return some weird error about a 'what' function (can't remember the exact output since I'm not on my work computer). However, when I was walking home, I think I might have found a solution. I haven't tested it yet but once I do and it works, I'll update with an answer. It's probably something to the effect of appending `width = NULL` to tabs and then making the call, e.g. `do.call(tabBox, c(tabs, width = NULL))`

Comment: This worked for me:`do.call(what = shinydashboard::tabBox, args = c(width = 5, tabs))`